# App crashing when using background image for navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using background image for the navigation bar. And it is crashing my app while presenting a view controller. I am also having the background image for all the view controller's view.
I am using implementing like this

```
func setNavigationAppearance(tintColor : UIColor, barTintColor : UIColor?) {
    let navigationBarAppearace = appDelegateObj.navigationController!.navigationBar

    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = tintColor
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = barTintColor
    navigationBarAppearace.translucent = false

    //navigationBarAppearace.
    //Settign the Custome Font and TextColor

    if let font = UIFont(name: FontCustom.Regular, size: 17) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font ,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : tintColor]
    }
}
```

I call this method with this image
let navigationColor : UIColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: AppImagesName.PatternRed)!)

And I am getting these crash logs.

> terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation

I Googled about this, all are saying that remove the background image or this is iOS bug.

So please let me know what could be the solution.

Comment: Where is the code for setting background image for navigation bar?

Comment: @SathiReddy I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I am working on your issue...

Comment: I added the code ..please check.. Now i am uploading the sample project to GitHub and give link to test..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set background image to NavigationBar, use the following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if let myImage = UIImage(named: "navBarImage.jpg"){
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(myImage, for: .default)
        }


        return true
    }
```

A sample screenshot:

[image]

To test sample, please check my GitHub link:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/NavigationBarBackgroundImageSample

Comment: Thanks, I am testing.

Comment: Thanks it is working. It is not crashing yet. If it would crash I will let you know.